# Using interval to aggregate values from previous day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to aggregate current day's numbers using Max(date) and previous day's numbers using -interval  all in a case statement as follows.

```
select

product
  , sum(
    case
      when date_started = max(date_started)
        then volume
    end
  )
  as "Current day's Volume"
  , sum(
    case
      when date_started = max(date_started)
        then revenue
    end
  )
  as "Current day's Revenue"
  , sum(
    case
      when date_started = (max(date_started) - interval '1 day' then volume end) as "Current day's Volume"
      , sum(
        case
          when date_started = (max(date_started) - interval '1 day' then revenue end) as "Current day's Revenue"
        from
          [lifetime_data]

       group by
          1
```

This is on PostgreSQL. It's not working and there are no obvious errors to me.

Comment: To understand what you are trying to achieve, you should show us some sample data and the expected output based on that data (as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: `from [lifetime_data]` would be rejected by Postgres as the square brackets are invalid in an identifier in SQL

Comment: You have superfluous parenthesis in your query. Also you can't name two SUMs with the same name. Can't you just do a `SUM()` then a `GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', date_started)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "obvious" errors.  You are not looking close enough.  Your first aggregation is:

```
sum(case when date_started = max(date_started)
^ aggregation function   ----^ nested aggregation function
        then volume
    end)
```

You have nested aggregation functions.  This is not allowed.

This answers the question about what the error is.

It is quite unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  If you want help fixing the query, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712827/using-max-date-and-interval-to-aggregate-values-for-previous-day?noredirect=1#comment103719024_58712827

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712827/using-max-date-and-interval-to-aggregate-values-for-previous-day?noredirect=1#comment103719024_58712827  
Here's the new question, Is there a way to work this out without nesting the agg function...Already tried the solution provided here, not working as expected