# Using max date and interval to aggregate values for previous day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to aggregate current day's numbers using Max(date) and previous day's numbers using -interval all in a case statement as follows.

```
select  product
      , sum(
            case
            when date_started = max(date_started)
            then volume
            end )
      as "Current day's Volume"
      , sum(
            case
            when date_started = max(date_started)
            then revenue
            end )
      as "Current day's Revenue"
      , sum(
            case
            when date_started = (max(date_started) - interval '1 day' 
            then volume 
             end ) as "previous day's Volume"
      , sum(
            case
            when date_started = (max(date_started) - interval '1 day' 
            then revenue 
             end ) as "Previous day's Revenue"
  from  lifetime_data
 group by 1
```

This is on PostgreSQL. It's not working.

**SAMPLE DATA**
[image: sample]

**EXPECTED RESULTS**
[image: results]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with a subquery and window functions:

```
select product,
       sum(volume) filter (where date_started = max_date_started) as current_day_volume,
       sum(revenue) filter (where date_started = max_date_started) as current_day_revenue,
       sum(volume) filter (where date_started = max_date_started - interval '1 day') as previous_day_volume,
       sum(revenue) filter (where date_started = max_date_started - interval '1 day') as previous_day_revenue
from (select ld.*,
             max(date_started) over (partition by product) as max_date_started
      from lifetime_data ld
     ) ld
group by product;
```